# Convert integer array to character array in C

Tags: arrays, c, malloc

I need to know how we can convert integer array to character array in C.
I have 1000 elements int array and I will have 4000 byte sized char array.
How to fill each integer elements into character array so that when printed all integers are shown in single string.
Example: dsid_list[3] = {1000, 1001, 1002};
Then char_dsid_array should have "100010011002"
Below is the code snippet trying to perform same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        uint32_t dsid_count = 1000;

        printf("dsid_count:%lu\n",dsid_count);

        uint32_t dsid_list[dsid_count];
        uint32_t i;

        printf("start\n");
        for(i=0; i<dsid_count; i++) {
                dsid_list[i] = i;
        }
        printf("Size of dsid_list:%lu\n", sizeof(dsid_list));

        //char char_dsid_array[sizeof(dsid_list)];
        char *char_dsid_array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(dsid_list) + 1);
        
        i=0;
        char* temp = (char*)malloc(4);
        char* temp1 = char_dsid_array;
        for(i=0; i<dsid_count; i++) {
                sprintf(temp, "%lu", dsid_list[i]);
                if(i == 0) {
                        strcpy(char_dsid_array, temp);
                }
                else {
                        strcat(char_dsid_array, temp);
                }
                char_dsid_array = char_dsid_array + 4;
        }
        char_dsid_array = temp1;
        printf("DSID list: %s\n", char_dsid_array);

        free(char_dsid_array);
        free(temp1);
        free(temp);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `%s` to print?  Do you expect the integer value `1` to print as the string `1`?  Do you want to account for endianness?  It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: You never write any data to `*temp`, so `strcpy(char_dsid_array, temp);` doesn't really make any sense.  Did you want to copy data *to* `temp`?  In that case, `temp` would be the first argument, but using `strcpy` is doomed to fail since that function expects its 2nd argument to be a null terminated array of characters, and you haven't correctly added null terminators.  The amount of data copied will depend on endianness, but mostly this is just a lot of UB.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I expect integer array to printed as a single string(Array of characters) as shown in example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Anyway, `uint32_t` can take values up to `4294967295` (2<sup>32</sup> - 1), so `4` bytes character space is not enough for storing that number as a string.
- Luckily, you're trying to create string using numbers in range `[0..999]`
- Just loop through the numbers and use return value from `sprintf()` to suffix numbers to the string. `sprintf()` (& `printf()` siblings) returns number of characters written to the target on success.

```c
// after malloc
    int slen = 0;
    for (int num = 0; num < dsid_count; ++num)
        slen += sprintf (char_dsid_array + slen, "%d", num);

    printf("DSID list: %s\n", char_dsid_array);
```

- However, if `DSID`s are indeed larger than number`1000`, then you need allocate sufficient space like `10010` (`10 x 1001` = `10010`) bytes for thousand such IDs to be on the safer side.
- Once done generating the string, use `realloc()` to trim unused memory if necessary, like:

```c
char* ptr = realloc (char_dsid_array, slen +1);
if (ptr) char_dsid_array = ptr;
else /* error handling */
```

Answer (score 0):

4 characters is enough to store the base-10 string representation of integers between 0 and 999, but in general it will no be enough to store an arbitrary `int`.  You can use `snprintf` to compute the amount of space you need to generate a string representation.  I would suggest accumulating the size you will need as you initialize the array and then allocate space once.  eg:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void * xmalloc(size_t s);

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    size_t dsid_count = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 1000;
    size_t needed = 0;
    printf("dsid_count:%zu\n", dsid_count);

    uint32_t *dsid_list = xmalloc(dsid_count * sizeof *dsid_list);
    uint32_t i;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < dsid_count; i+= 1 ){
        dsid_list[i] = i;
        needed += snprintf(NULL, 0, "%" PRIu32, dsid_list[i]);
    }

    char *int_string = xmalloc(needed + 1);
    char *end = int_string;
    size_t avail = needed + 1;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < dsid_count; i+= 1 ){
        int s = snprintf(end, avail, "%" PRIu32, dsid_list[i]);
        end += s;
        avail -= s;
    }
    assert( end - int_string == needed );
    printf("%s\n", int_string);
}


void *
xmalloc(size_t s)
{
    void *rv = malloc(s);
    if( rv == NULL ){
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t print(char *buff, size_t size, int *array)
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    int len = 0;

    while(size--)
    {
        len = snprintf(buff + (!!buff) * pos, !!buff * INT_MAX, "%d", *array++);
        if(len < 0) { /* error andling */}
        pos += len;
    }
    return pos;
}

char *printIntArray(size_t size, int *array)
{
    char *string = malloc(print(NULL, size, array) + 1);

    if(string) print(string, size, array);
    return string;
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[3] = {1000, 1001, 1002};
    char *b;
    printf("\"%s\"\n", b = printIntArray(3, array));
    free(b);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sir, down below there is code example for the case:

> dsid_list[3] = {1000, 1001, 1002}; Then char_dsid_array should have
> "100010011002"

Please note some secure issues, before add a new integer to the array we must check there is enough space, before concantenate I will if there is space enough:

`if(sizeof(my_list) > (strlen(str_number) + strlen(my_list)))`

Another cute security recourse is `snprintf`, this function improves `sprintf` to avoid overflow.

Here's an online working code [link](https://tio.run/##dVI9T8MwEN3zK05BiFoNNOFjqNIiIRZYGIANqsqNXcciuSDbHQD1t5dzEqcREh4s39d77@5cnKuiOBxONBbVTkhYWCd0c1HeRmOX0ai8LzoRcqtRwuPT6/r@4e75BbIMZjO4AVs2u0rARoLEZqfKBLI0Tc@z@XwO9pMjXIPQSjsLUzh7T88SX7nxNjehBraNIZ9S0jrQ6KSSBnBXb6SJIrKh5honLPqJgI53YD48K4nKlZ1dlNwAyV53xW@D3FXu1Vr9LYNgYlalA9dQfkNKeFX1QhOiJsNJU2vkFEwGLmG1WFfaurerFSzhx7faNpy19@V@JKP@6jKvKbpaQhznURvs9FK1V9NsJwMmg1nwERfr02k0E6TsNAeERegWcDplbbybiT8WP2lfbjs5DiA5LiyB@FTEyagFXLF8KNZU1nH3uhncgkciwhEgoy32zpDH2ABy1NLqcabgLuQlo72MePfDS1ZW/oPU9xU/NS78GPpahTxur/aX4I6/YzxC92djJP/4S9jdAbf@Ai@RpnxqaUShszzaHw6/)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INT_CHARS 11 // 5 should be enough, 1000-1999 span 4 digits + '\0', 11 bits are enough for biggest integer number

int main()
{
    int n;
    int length;
    char str_number[INT_CHARS]; // size should enoght to store all digits, null terminator,
    int dsid_list[3] = {1000, 1001, 1002};
    char my_list[4001]= "";

    length = sizeof(dsid_list) / sizeof(int);

    for(n = 0; n < length; n++)
    {
        snprintf(str_number, INT_CHARS, "%d", dsid_list[n]);
        if(sizeof(my_list) > (strlen(str_number) + strlen(my_list)))
        {
            strcat(my_list, str_number);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Not enough space to store more data\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("my list = %s", my_list);
}
```